# If you want to know $\sin (x)$ within $0.5$ of its true value, then how accurately do you need to know $x$?

Tags: numerical-methods

If you want to know $\sin (x)$ within $0.5$ of its true value, then how accurately do you need to know $x$?

I don't really understand how to think about this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since $|\sin'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$, you have (by the mean value theorem) $|\sin x - \sin y| \le  |x -y|$.

So a sufficient condition is that if you know $x$ within $0.5$ of the correct value, then $\sin x$ will be within $0.5$ of the correct value.

Comment: How do you know that $\left | \sin '(x) \right |\leq 1$ for all $x$?

Comment: $\sin' = \cos$, and $|\cos(x)| \le 1 $ for all $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$|\sin y-\sin x|=2\left|\cos\frac{x+y}2\cdot\right|\cdot\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\cdot\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$
so that $|x-y|<2\arcsin\frac 14\approx 0.50536$ is sufficient. This is *slightly* better than the $0.5$ obtained from $\sin'x$ alone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Taylor's formula.